# Replace String.Replace with Regex.Replace

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, replace

**OLD**:

```
private string Check_long(string input)
{
    input = input.Replace("cool", "supercool");
    input = input.Replace("cool1", "supercool1");
    input = input.Replace("cool2", "supercool2");
    input = input.Replace("cool3", "supercool3");
    return input;
}
```

**NEW**:

```
private string Check_short(string input)
{    
    input = Regex.Replace(input, "cool", "supercool", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    input = Regex.Replace(input, "cool1", "supercool1", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    input = Regex.Replace(input, "cool2", "supercool2", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    input = Regex.Replace(input, "cool3", "supercool3", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return input;
}
```

The old solution with `String.Replace` was working just fine. But it didn't support case-insensitivity. So I had to check for `Regex.Replace`, but now it won't work. Why is that ?

Comment: The method names are different...?

Comment: What do you mean by "won't work"? Are we supposed to guess what the problem is?

Comment: By 'it won't work', I mean that the string doesn't get replaced.
What I used to do is check a user's input and in case it contained "cool", "cool1" etc.,
I replaced the text.

Now that I've changed it to Regex, it doesn't replace the user's input.

Could the problem be that I'm trying to run multiple replacements on the same input string ?

Comment: Could it be a problem that I it's actually not just a word, but "cool. " or "  cool.  " ?

Comment: I've written a quick example of my version of your method in action - see http://ideone.com/Pbywh - works fine and replaces the text as expected.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your new code should work fine.  Note that you can also retain the case of your input using a [capture group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html):

```
private string Check_short(string input)
{    
    return Regex.Replace(input, "(cool)", "super$1", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

Comment: @dll32 - only if you want to capture it. The regex "cool" would also work perfectly fine, you just wouldn't have access to $1 in the replacement string..

Comment: Can you please take a quick look at http://ideone.com/dv4aL | I want "Mm" to be replaced my "mark" and not by "peter". It somehow seems to interpretate "MM" the same as "M ". Well seems like Regex is more complex than I thought....

Comment: If you switch your two replace statements it'll work as you intend - the problem is that your first replace "(M )" matches _both_ statements, because they both have an M character followed by a space character.

Answer (score 5):

working fine here:

```
        string input = "iiii9";
        input = Regex.Replace(input, "IIII[0-9]", "jjjj" , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        label1.Text = input;
```

output

```
jjjj
```

Answer (score -2):

Regex do not work the say way that string.replace does. You need to build the regex around what you are trying to filter for.

```
private string Check_short(string input)
{    
    input = Regex.Replace(input, ".*(cool).*", "supercool", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return input;
}
```

Comment: Actually, `"cool"` is a valid regex that simply matches the string `cool`.

Comment: your regex will replace _all_ text in the input string with the text `supercool` if input contains `cool`, not _just_ the cool bit.. It'll work better without the `.*`s